# Find the solution for this Homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra

5x1−5x2+10x  =  0
3x1+ax2+5x3  =  0
2x1−3x2+5x3  =  0

how to find the solutions from a value

```
5 -5 10|0
3  a  5|0
2 -3  5|0
```

No solution 
Unique solution 
Infinitly many solution

Comment: Compute the determinant of that matrix.  You will get a degree-one polynomial in the variable a.  For some values of a, the determinant will be 0, and for other values of a, it won't.  This will help you determine what values of a produce a system with a unique solution or infinitely many solutions.  There will always be at least one solution, because the matrix is square.  In particular, no matter what a is, (0,0,0) is always a solution.  Do you see this?

Answer (score 0):

Just see that if *a=-2* then sum of second and third rows equals the first row thereby giving **det(A)=0**.

Hence *a=-2* will give infinitely many solutions while for any *a€R* it has a trivial solution **x=y=z=0**